# Generics Broken Quicksort

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, quicksort

my tutor suggested I should post my problem on stackover flow, because this is not something my professor covered (he's going to cover it). Still it's a grade. I understand quick sort, and the rest of my program works, but no matter what I try my quicksort will not function.

This assignment is meant for us to practice using generics on our own. Our professor has not taught us how; he expects us to learn. I've tried: CompareTo, loop operands of < and >. Tried reading the textbook, but didn't find a solution to my issue. I've also tried working with my project partners, but they've given up on the class and refuse to help me. It's still a grade, so I'm completing it on my own. I'll just post the relevant part of the code

```
     public static <E extends Comparable> int partition(E[] list,int low, int high) {
    E pivot =  list[low];
    int i = low - 1;
    int j = high + 1;
    while (i < j)
    {
    for (i++; (int) list[i] < pivot i++);
    for (j--; (int) list[j] > pivot; j--);
    if (i < j)
    swap(i, j);
    }
    return j;
    }
    }
```

The output should produce a sorted list from the driver.

Comment: `;` terminates your loop bodies so you have two empty for loops and then one `if` in a `while`. Also, why are you comparing `i` and `j`? Are you paying your tutor?

Comment: Hello and welcome! First, "This assignment is meant for us to practice using generics on our own." it seems like getting advice from a tutor, working in a group and posting on StackOverflow goes against the purpose of the assignment. Anyways, what is the actual problem you are having? "It will not function" is not exactly a clear problem statement.

Comment: Here's a Java code style guideline that my various employers have used: Optional braces are not optional. That is, you wouldn't say if (condition) blah. You would say if (condition) { blah }. While the language allows for a single line for a code block (if, for, while, etc), and it's less fluff to exclude the braces, it opens you to an entire huge class of programming errors that can be subtle to see. So, we don't treat optional braces as optional, and we don't run into those weird classes of errors as a result.

Comment: Have you learned about recursion yet? I tried looking up a good tutorial that you could use, but they all seem to use recursion.

Comment: I learned a little recursion on my own. I think I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is similar to Hoare partition scheme. Choosing [low] for pivot will be worst case for already sorted data, and typical Hoare scheme will infinitely recurse if [high] is chosen for pivot. One of the for loops seems to be missing an internal semi-colon. Below is a typical Hoare partition scheme.

```
    public static <E extends Comparable> void quicksort(E[] list, int low, int high)
    {
        if(low >= high)
            return;
        int index = partition(list, low, high);
        quicksort(list, low, index);
        quicksort(list, index+1, high);
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable> int partition(E[] list, int low, int high)
    {
        E pivot = list[low+(high-low)/2];
        int i = low - 1;
        int j = high + 1;
        while (true)
        {
            while(list[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
            while(list[--j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);
            if(i >= j)
                break;
            E temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
        return j;
    }
```

To avoid stack overflow for worst case data patterns:

```
    public static <E extends Comparable> void quicksort(E[] list, int low, int high)
    {
        while(low < high)
        {
            int index = partition(list, low, high);
            if((index - low) <= (high - index)){
                quicksort(list, low, index);
                low = index+1;
            } else {
                quicksort(list, index+1, high);
                high = index;
            }
        }
    }
```